# Angular - deploying project on server

Tags: angular, server

I have a question.
I have to deploy my Angular project on server, but when I copy files created by "ng build" (from 'dist' folder) page don't show up.
I did "Tour of Heroes" tutorial.

Comment: What is your "server"?

Comment: my servier is: ssh sigma

Comment: The other way i was trying to do it is by GitHub but same result here:
https://padamaszek.github.io/FrontendDev/

Comment: Try `ng build --prod`.

Comment: your server should be configurated to serve static files, in the case of an angular project, the index.html file

Comment: i did `ng build --prod` but still effect like in previous link

Comment: Mayby i have some bad routing?
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body background="background.jpg">
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
`

Comment: [here is my index.html after build](https://pastebin.com/msGQZ8j5)

Comment: I did website but page don't show up. Why ?